# got more than 100 tweets but loading is taking too much time

Tags: php

I am doing a project on twitter analytics with rest api 1.1 xampp server ok so i want to get more than 100 tweets on particular hashtag even i am able to get more than 100 tweet with following code:

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "xxx",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxx",
'consumer_key' => "xxx",
'consumer_secret' => "xxx"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$since_id=0;
$c=1;
$cc=1;
for(;$cc<=500;)
{
$getfield = '?    q='.$_POST["hash"].'&result_type=recent&count=200&lang=en&since_id='.$since_id.'';
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);
error_reporting(0);//echo "Count: ". $cc ."";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
foreach($string as $val)
{
      $since_id=$val['max_id_str'];

}
?>
<html>
<body>
<ul style="list-style: none;" >
<?php 
foreach($string["statuses"] as $items)
{
?>
<li>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td rowspan=4 width=100><img src=<?php echo $items['user']['profile_image_url'];?> width=44 height=44> </td>
</tr>
<td width=600><?php echo "Count: ". $c ."";?></td>
<tr>
<td width=600><?php echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=600><?php echo "Location is: ". $items['user']['location']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  width=600><?php  echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  width=600><?php echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items["created_at"]; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</li>
<?php $c++;
}
$cc++;
}
?>    
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

but the problem is this taking too much time to load like some time hour or half an hour any solution??

Thank You.

Comment: LOL you have just posted something  secrete (app secrete) here

Comment: You might want to try using xdebug to profile your code; that will tell you what is taking the majority of the execution time.  http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler.  If it's taking 30 minutes I would suggest cutting it down slightly for the purposes of profiling; like only execution 100 iterations of the outer loop instead of all 500.  Otherwise the trace files get unmanageable.  The output is still generally useful provided an average loop iteration isn't much different from a peak execution time loop iteration.

Comment: Despite Hanky Panky has edited out the credentials you should not reveal, you should immediately change them.

Comment: O cmon!!! that keys were incorrect i had just written some random numbers .